# IPC between Python and C#

Tags: c#, python, ipc, rpc, bidirectional

I want to pass data between a Python and a C# application in Windows (I want the channel to be bi-directional)
In fact I wanna pass a struct containing data about a network packet that I've captured with C# (SharpPcap) to the Python app and then send back a modified packet to the C# program.
What do you propose ? (I rather it be a fast method)
My searches so far revealed that I can use these technologies, but I don't know which:

1. JSON-RPC
2. Use WCF (run the project
   under IronPython using Ironclad)
3. WCF (use Python for .NET)

Comment: You sort of answered yourself. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a simple socket communication, or if you wish you can start a simple http server, and/or do json-rpc over it.

Comment: Are there any JSON-RPC implementation for both C# and Python that support bidirectional communication ?

Comment: not sure abt JSON-RPC, but for your purpose why you need JSON-RPC, just send the packet data over socket/http and return it back after processing, like a web api

Answer (score 2):

Use JSON-RPC because the experience that you gain will have more practical use. JSON is widely used in web applications written in all of the dozen or so most popular languages.