# Python Scripting in C# pass values through C# and getting return value from python code

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I am making a GUI in C# and doing python scripting using iron python. But i want to pass a value from C# code to python code and get the return value to show in my gui. Is it possible???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IPC between Python and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700228/ipc-between-python-and-c-sharp)